# Compactification of spacetimes always possible?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, spacetime-dimensions

Consider a metric in a $n+1$ dimensional spacetime given by
\begin{equation}
g=\underbrace{g_{tt}(r,t)dt^2 + g_{rt}(r,t)drdt + g_{rr} dr^2}_{g'} +h(t,r,x^A)dx^Adx^B
\end{equation}
where $h$ is a $n-1$ dimensional Riemannian metric. We can always compactify the spacetime when the metric $g'$ is a two dimensional lorentzian metric of the from
\begin{equation}
g'= g_{uv}(u,v)dvdu = g_{uv}(-dt^2+dr^2).
\end{equation}
But can we always bring a two-dimensional loretzian metric to this form?

Comment: Is any two-dimensional metric conformally flat perhaps?

Comment: In fact this question (v2) seems to be about $1+1D$ rather than $n+1D$. Consider to remove irrelevant parts of question.